# std_msgs/sensors_msgs does not name a type

Tags: ros2, sensor-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have a project with 2 files a main .cpp and a .hpp. The .cpp includes

```
#include "sensor_msgs/msg/nav_sat_fix.h"
```

and declares a variable

```
sensor_msgs::msg::NavSatFix n;
```

and this works just fine.

When I try to do the same thing by including sensor message in the .hpp file I get a colcon message stating that `sensor_msgs` does not name a type, even though I declared it identically to the .cpp reference.

My `package.xml` depends on sensor_msgs and my `CMakeLists.txt` finds sensor_msgs is listed as one of the ament_target_dependencies. The same thing happens if I include a std_msg in the .hpp section so I assume its some path missing somewhere, but I'm not sure why it works for the .cpp and not the .hpp.

**UPDATE:**
Here is a simplified mini-project to show the issue I'm having

**CMakeList.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(testing)

# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(sensor_msgs REQUIRED)


include_directories("../dependencies/")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} a.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} rclcpp std_msgs sensor_msgs obstacle_msgs)


install(TARGETS
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

ament_package()
```

**package.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
  <name>testing</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>blah blah blah</description>

  <maintainer email="paul@somewhere.com">Paul</maintainer>
  <license>TODO</license>
  <!-- <author email="paul">Paul</author> -->

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>
  <depend>rclcpp</depend>
  <depend>std_msgs</depend>
  <depend>sensor_msgs</depend>
  
  <!-- The export tag contains other, unspecified, tags -->
  <export>
    <!-- Other tools can request additional information be placed here -->
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

**a.cpp:**

```
#include "b.hpp"

int main()
{
    B *b = new B();

    return 0;
}
```

**b.hpp:**

```
#ifndef SRC_TEST_B_HPP_
#define SRC_TEST_B_HPP_

#include "sensor_msgs/msg/nav_sat_fix.h"

class B {
public:
    sensor_msgs::msg::NavSatFix getPoly() { return m_polygon; }
private:
    sensor_msgs::msg::NavSatFix m_polygon;
};

#endif /* SRC_TEST_B_HPP_ */
```

**Compiling output:**

```
In file included from /home/paul/code/eclipse_ws/ROS2/src/testing/a.cpp:1:0:
/home/paul/code/eclipse_ws/ROS2/src/testing/b.hpp:8:2: error: ‘sensor_msgs’ does not name a type
  sensor_msgs::msg::NavSatFix getPoly() { return m_polygon; }
  ^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/paul/code/eclipse_ws/ROS2/src/testing/b.hpp:10:2: error: ‘sensor_msgs’ does not name a type
  sensor_msgs::msg::NavSatFix m_polygon;
```

What simple thing am I missing?

Sincerely, Paul.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326090/std_msgs/sensors_msgs-does-not-name-a-type/) by [AwooOOoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/42876/awoooooo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 117 on 2019-06-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-18**:
Pedantic, but:

> I get a colcon message

it's actually the compiler (probably GCC if compiling on Linux) tells you that it can't find the type. Colcon is not the compiler.

---

Edit: please show (the relevant parts) of your `CMakeLists.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You seem to be importing a C header and use it as if it was containing C++ classes.

Did you try importing the C++ version of the message instead?

```
#include "sensor_msgs/msg/nav_sat_fix.hpp"
```

If you are porting packages from ROS 1, you can refer to [this documentation page](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Contributing/Migration-Guide/) that provides useful tips for how to update package.xml, header inclusion etc

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2019-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AwooOOoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/42876/awoooooo/) on 2019-06-18**:
I can't believe it was that simple.... Thank you =)